# bootstrap classes in table in quarto r

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, quarto

I am trying to replicate a simple example from [quarto documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/tables.html#using-bootstrap-classes)

It is supposed to give me "stripes" on hover which is not happening...

My code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: 
  html:
    theme:
      light: cosmo
---

| fruit  | price  |
|--------|--------|
| apple  | 2.05   |
| pear   | 1.37   |
| orange | 3.09   |

: Fruit prices {.striped .hover}
```

the {} part is in the heading, not processed...

Where am i wrong?
[image]